# NSSharingService instance return nil in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, share

I downloaded the sample code on NSSharingService from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SharingServices/Listings/Sharing_APLAppDelegate_m.html. The code is not working as i am not able to launch mail app from this. On debugging i found that [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail] is always returning nil. Can someone please guide me if there is any system set up required to launch this successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Facebook service (NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook).
It is nil when "System Preferences -> Internet Accounts -> Facebook -> Share Menu" is turned off.

A sheet appeared first time and asked to add an account, I added one and just disabled that option and had to debug a code for about an hour.

As for your issue with Mail, it should be something similar, something with Mail accounts configuration. I tried myself to disable all Mail accounts, but it picked my Gmail one, so I was not able to reproduce it. Also I have no ability yet to test with a non-configured Mail.

Hope this will help you to go in the right direction.